# MySQL INSERT if record exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

having a little trouble with a query that I'd like to keep to just one query. Basically, I have two tables, users, and relationships. Users have an ID, the relationships table has user_a and user_b fields which contain users.id values, which matches users up as 'user_a follows user_b'.

Now I'm hitting the Twitter API to pull in user_a's followers (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) but people in the users table are people attending an event, and not necessarily in user_a's friends. I need to execute an INSERT in the relationships table if user_b exists in the users table.

Here's what I have so far!

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=' . $this->_attendee->id);
$response = json_decode($json);
if($response->ids){
    foreach($response->ids as $friend){
        // query goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe with triggers, directly at MySQL level. I don't remember exactly what level of customization triggers allow...

Comment: I think you're looking for: `$itll->be()->reet();`

Answer (score 4):

Build a select statement that returns the line you want to add exactly if the user entry exists. Then do INSERT INTO user_a SELECT YOUR_STATEMENT;

eg. INSERT INTO user_a SELECT uid, "value1", 2, "some other string" FROM user_b WHERE uid=$friend;

Comment: Thanks, solved it with `INSERT INTO relationships (user_a,user_b) VALUES ('43849096', (SELECT id FROM attendees WHERE id=2946339244));`

Comment: That gives null if user_b doesn't have a matching entry, right? It wasn't very clear from your question what should happen in that case - my statement doesn't insert anything at all.